# Product's price messing with multiple stores

Tags: magento-1.9, websites, associate-products

I have 2 websites in my Magento, each website has it store view with an specific language, currency, etc. All products are in both websites but with different prices (I changed the scope and defined each product price for each website).

One of my products (let's say product X) is a configurable product which has products A, B and C as options (these last 3 are simple products). Product X price is $50 but if I choose option C, I have a discount of $10.

So, inside Product X, in the tab **Associated Products**, I have products A, B and C, having C with -10 in the price field.

Everything was working fine before, but after adding a new website and setting these products to show in both stores, this discount seems to be duplicated. When I go to the product's list page, Magento shows **As low as $30** for product X, but should be $40.

Any ideas?

*Ps.: I tried to explain the situation as better as I could, but feel free to ask more details.*

Comment: you need to make sure that you are saving the product first before switching store and updating new prices, this is a common issue

Comment: Thank you @robin, but I am doing that...when I go back to the products, I can see that the information is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best way to actually work with multiple currencies is using Magento currency rates instead of creating new prices to each product.

I removed all custom prices from my products and let Magento convert it based on the rates and everything is working fine now.